# Torch installment fails in Elastic Beanstalk web application

Tags: python, pytorch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a basic web application using Elastic Beanstalk from AWS.
My app is written in python and uses pyTorch library so it can import NLP model named "bart-cnn-large" (with it I can produce text summarization).

I have a file named requirements.txt and with it the EC2 sets the virtual environment.
However, it always fails when trying to install the pytorch library.

- If I remove "torch" from the requirements.txt then the installation doesn't fail anymore.
  but I get this message:

  > None of PyTorch, TensorFlow >= 2.0, or Flax have been found. Models
  > won't be available and only tokenizers, configuration and file/data
  > utilities can be used.
- If I leave "torch" in requirements I get this message:

  > 2021/08/06 10:54:23.688955 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution
  > of command [app-deploy] - [InstallDependency]. Stop running the
  > command. Error: fail to install dependencies with requirements.txt
  > file with error Command /bin/sh -c
  > /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
  > failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:ERROR: Invalid requirement:
  > 'torch==1.9.0+cu102 torchvision==0.10.0+cu102 torchaudio===0.9.0'
  > (from line 1 of requirements.txt)

the requirments.txt content:

```
>torch==1.9.0+cu102 torchvision==0.10.0+cu102 torchaudio===0.9.0 -f
https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html  
Flask~=2.0.1
Werkzeug~=2.0.1  
tika~=1.24  
beautifulsoup4~=4.8.2  
docx2txt~=0.8
transformers~=4.8.2 
clean-text
```

I tried several versions of "pip torch" but none seems to work.
is this a storage problem? why won't it install?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: sadly no. I used HuggingFace API to get my data

Comment: if anyone comes to this and finds a way, please reply.  any app that has torch doesn't seem to work on EB